# How to intepret coefficients for interaction of factor variables?

Tags: r, categorical-data, glmm

Is there a trick to interpreting the coefficients for a two-way interaction of factor variables? Both variables in the model have 3+ levels making this more complex than a simple binary explanation. If I would like to, for example, compare the reference level (Age:'adult') and (Phone:'a') to (Age:'4') and (Phone:'a'), how can I do that? Or is that not possible given that the interaction of Phone and Age is significant?

```
Conditional model:

             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    

(Intercept)  -2.54836    0.18971 -13.433  < 2e-16 ***
Age4         -0.17299    0.27524  -0.629  0.52966    
Age5         -0.24961    0.25707  -0.971  0.33155    
Age6         -0.35963    0.25756  -1.396  0.16262    
Age7         -0.30664    0.23373  -1.312  0.18953    
Age8          0.26975    0.25890   1.042  0.29745    
Age9         -0.74884    0.29226  -2.562  0.01040 *  
Age10        -0.93972    0.28689  -3.276  0.00105 ** 
Phoneu        0.46365    0.08013   5.786 7.20e-09 ***
Phonei       -0.74388    0.06814 -10.917  < 2e-16 ***
Age4:Phoneu   0.77067    0.14018   5.498 3.85e-08 ***
Age5:Phoneu   0.73788    0.11845   6.230 4.68e-10 ***
Age6:Phoneu   0.73057    0.12290   5.944 2.77e-09 ***
Age7:Phoneu   1.11940    0.10809  10.356  < 2e-16 ***
Age8:Phoneu   0.02406    0.13587   0.177  0.85945    
Age9:Phoneu   1.07146    0.14338   7.473 7.83e-14 **
Age10:Phoneu  0.75347    0.15001   5.023 5.09e-07 ***
Age4:Phonei   1.00427    0.12255   8.195 2.51e-16 ***
Age5:Phonei   1.03498    0.10238  10.109  < 2e-16 ***
Age6:Phonei   1.02321    0.10249   9.983  < 2e-16 ***
Age7:Phonei   0.84565    0.09787   8.640  < 2e-16 ***
Age8:Phonei   0.18047    0.11470   1.573  0.11562    
Age9:Phonei   1.19847    0.11603  10.329  < 2e-16 ***
Age10:Phonei  1.27235    0.12078  10.535  < 2e-16 ***
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could interpret that.
Your intercept shows the predicated value of logit (you did not specify the model type) when Age is 'adult' and Phone is 'a'.
The coefficient next to "Age4" shows the difference in the fitted value (of logit) between "Age 4, Phone a" and the reference point, "Age 10, Phone a". But as you see, it is statistically non-significant, i.e., it can be assumed to be the same as for Age 10.

You can also interpret the numbers for predictors in interaction terms if the other part of the interaction is set to the reference level. E.g., 0.46365 is how much higher the fitted value (of logit) for "Phone u" is estimated as compared to "Phone a" (the reference), if Age is 10 (the reference).

If you would like to see all of the coefficients in action, it is often convenient to plot them. sjPlot can do that well.

Comment: Yes but how to interpret the interaction coefficient for one level, for example, 'Phone a' and 'Age 4' and a reference level of 'Phone a' and 'Age adult'? The current reference level of 'Phone a' only allows me to compare the reference level to 'Phone u' and 'Age 4' or 'Phone i' and 'Age 4'. I want to compare the reference level 'Phone a' and 'Age adult' to 'Phone a' and 'Age 4'.

Comment: If you want to know the interaction for 'Phone a' and 'Age 4', you might want to change the reference level as there is no interaction effect for them now. 'Phone a' is your base level, and you estimate the difference in slopes for two other Phone by Age combinations. Currently, the coefficient for 'Age 4' shows you the difference between 'Age adult' and 'Age 4', provided that they are both estimated for 'Phone a'.